# SQL Server heartbeat monitoring

Tags: sql-server

I wish to script the below scenario.

I have list of 100 SQL Servers (there are few named instances as well). My goal is to

1. Read each server from the table/textpad .
2. Try to establish connection with Username and password provided. (It's a high privileged windows account, common for all servers.)

   NOTE : SQLCMD ,T-SQL or POWERSHELL would do.
3. Check if  server is online. If yes,

   *) Skip it and go to next server or instance in the list.
4. If no,

   *) need to throw a mail that server/instance is down.

Comment: there's tons of examples online where people have done this they way you have noted.  for example: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/monitoring-sql-server-agent-with-powershell or http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3752866/Check-your-SQL-Server-using-Windows-PowerShell-150-Part-1.htm

Answer (score 0):

Note that for Step 2 if you are connecting with integrated security (i.e. Windows account), your thread needs to be running under that account BEFORE attempting to connect to SQL Server.  You do not have the ability to specify a Windows account at the connection level.